# Defining a runtime environment

Tags: language-agnostic, deployment, runtime

I need to define a runtime environment for my development. The first idea is of course not to reinvent the wheel. I downloaded macports, used easy_install, tried fink. I always had problems. Right now, for example, I am not able to compile scipy because the MacPorts installer wants to download and install gcc43, but this does not compile on Snow Leopard. A bug is open for this issue, but I am basically tied to them for my runtime to be usable.

A technique I learned some time ago, was to write a makefile to download and build the runtime/libs with clearly specified versions of libraries and utilities. This predates the MacPorts/fink/apt approach, but you have much more control on it, although you have to do everything by hand. Of course, this can become a nightmare on its own if the runtime grows, but if you find a problem, you can use `patch` and fix the issue on the downloaded package, then build it.

I have multiple questions:

- What is your technique to prepare a well-defined runtime/library collection for your development?
- Does MacPorts/fink/whatever allows me the same flexibility of rehacking if something goes wrong ?
- Considering my makefile solution, when my software is finally out for download, what are your suggestions about solving the potential troubles between my development environment and the actual platform on my user's machines ?

**Edit**: What I don't understand in particular is that other projects don't give me hints. For example, I just downloaded scipy, a complex library with lots of dependencies. Developers must have all the deps setup before working on it. Despite this, there's nothing in the svn that creates this environment.

**Edit**: Added a bounty to the question. I think this is an important issue and it deserves to get more answers. I will consider best those answers with real world examples with particular attention towards any arisen issues and their solution.

Additional questions to inspire for the Bounty:

- Do you perform testing on your environment (to check proper installation, e.g. on an integration machine) ?
- How do you include your environment at shipping time ? If it's C, do you statically link it, or ship the dynamic library, tinkering the LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running the executable? What about the same issue for python, perl, and other ?
- Do you stick to the runtime, or update it as time passes? Do you download "trunk" packages of your dependency libraries or a fixed version?
- How do you deal with situations like: library foo needs python 2.5, but you need to develop in python 2.4 because library bar does not work with python 2.5 ?

Comment: Aside: I can not express how much I loath the use of "runtime" to mean "a set of linkable libraries and OS services". From whence comes this abomination? Who can I *blame*?

Comment: You can find some answers here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_system

Comment: I looked at that, but it offers neither a date of first use, nor a target for my vitriol. Not helpful in this context.

Comment: BTW-- At least with fink, you can take the packages apart, and see what---if anything---the maintainer did to make it compile on the mac. In some cases this makes it east to build your own package to support another version. Also, it is worth contacting the maintainer and offering to help.

Comment: Yeap! I need to compile scipy to develop my own project, and end up participating in a completely different task. That's going to happen ;)

Comment: You are already threatening to build the needed packages from source. If that is trivial than fink packaging is a small job. If the build is non-trivial, then working with someone who has already done it might help.

Comment: fact is, I already dropped fink because it had other major problems with Snow Leopard. MacPorts appeared to be much better. In any case, I cannot afford to wait for an official release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a CMake script that generates Makefiles that download (mainly through SVN)/configure/build all our dependencies. Why CMake? Multiplatform. This works quite well, and we support invocation of scons/autopain/cmake. As we build on several platforms (Windows, MacOSX, a bunch of Linux variants) we also support different compile flags etc based on the operating system. Typically a library has a default configuration, and if we encounter a system that needs special configuration the configuration is replaced with a specialized configuration. This works quite well. We did not really find any ready solution that would fit our purpose.

That being said, it is a PITA to get it up and running - there's a lot of knobs to turn when you need to support several operating systems. I don't think it will become a maintainance-nightmare as the dependencies are quite fixed (libraries are upgraded regularly, but we rarely introduce new one).

Comment: So basically you use the personalized download/build script approach.

Comment: Yupp =) But rather than using Makefiles directly we use CMake that generates Makefiles or NMake Makfiles. We feel that this gives us more flexibility and less headaches than using Makefiles directly.

Comment: Seems strange that there's nothing more streamlined for a problem that I guess is pervasive in the software industry.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's because it's very hard to make a system that actually works for C++. You have tons of compilers, operating systems and generally you need to handle each of them separately - unfortunately. For Java, you might use Maven which covers everything from dependencies, building, testing and shipping through the "build"scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[virtualenv](http://arthurkoziel.com/2008/10/22/working-virtualenv/) is good, but it can't do magic - e.g. if you want use a library that just MUST have Python 2.4 *and* another one that absolutely NEEDS 2.5 instead, you're out of luck. Nor can virtualenv (or any other tool) help when there's a brand new release of an OS and half the tools &c just don't support it yet, as you mentioned for Snow Leopard: some problems are just impossible to solve (two libraries with absolutely conflicting needs within the same build), others just require patience (until all tools you need are ported to the new OS's release, you just need to stick with the previous OS release).